# Update method using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm want to update a book from my book database using typescript, node js and mongodb and I can't find a good way to make it. This is how i tried but i doesn't work

```
const updateBook = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        const id = req.params.bookId;
    
        Book.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: id}, req.body)
            .exec()
            .then((result) => {
                return res.status(200).json(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    message: error.message,
                    error
                });
            });
    };
```

this is the route i want to use

```
router.put('/put/:bookId', controller.updateBook);
```

Comment: What ORM are you using? Mongoose?

Comment: In what way it does not work? Is it throwing an error? Has it simply not updated the book? Make sure that the book is already in the DB when trying to update it :)

Comment: yes, i'm using mongoose

Comment: it's not throwing an error, it just does not update the book that i want. The book is already there

Comment: Mongoose returns the original document (pre-updates) by default. If the document in the database is updated, but the object you receive in the callback is the book without the updates, you might need to set `returnOriginal` setting to false. Let me know if that was it and I'll post it as the answer ;)

Comment: Impossible to actually answer this without you giving us more info, what is `req.body`? is the `_id` being cast to `ObjectID` by a sanitizor in the route?  are you able to just `findOne` without the update and get a match?